# What are good elementary examples for teaching/introducing/learning about Intuitionistic Logic or Heyting Algebras?

Tags: logic, education

For example, I have heard of a topological one wherein negation means the interior of the complement (but still would like a reference).

Comment: The wikipedia entry for intuitionistic logic http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic gives some references and in particular has a little bit to say about the topological interpretation you aluded to. See the section "Heyting Algebra Semantics".

Answer (score 2):

The example that you mention in you question is explained in Maclane and Moerdijk  's book [Sheaves in Geom and Logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540977104) very near the beginning. They discuss this in relation to Heyting algebras for the purpose of Topos Theory. This book is very very nice, I highly recommend it.

Comment: I love this book! Although, I've only read very small parts of it.

Comment: @Matt, It is very nice, I like it a lot also.

Answer (score 1):

An excellent book is also [http://www.amazon.com/Lectures-Curry-Howard-Isomorphism-Foundations-Mathematics/dp/0444520775](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0444520775).  This book is more focused on the $\lambda$-Calculus but it has some really excellent sections on general intuitionist logic, including Heyting Algebras, Hilbert Proofs, the (Gentzen's) sequent calculus and things like that.